# How to display the key, values on screen stored in hasp map using android

Tags: android, dictionary, android-listview, hashmap, screen

I am new to android.I read contacts as name and phone number data which is stored in csv File and to store in map interface Name as key and Phone no as value.I am in need to add my Hash map Key,value data into List view and to display it on the screen for user visible Here my code is 
        Map maps = new HashMap();

```
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] contact = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                       // contact[0]- name as key and contact[1]-phoneno as value
            maps.put(contact[0], contact[1]);

        }
```

From that how to add these key,value pair into List view

Answer (score 0):

You have to use adapter. Read about android adapters.

You can look at this basic example. 'list_item' is the layout of your list item. For better performance use holder (read about that).

### After creating this adapter you have to set it in you ListView. listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

```
public class Contact{
              String name;
              String phoneNumber;
        }

       public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
           private List<Contact> objects;

           public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> objects){
           super(context,R.layout.list_item, objects);
           this.objects = objects;

       }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                  if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)     context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

                     TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);

                     TextView phoneNumber= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sound_label);

                     name.setText(objects.get(position).name);
                     phoneNumber.setText(objects.get(position).phoneNumer);
                     return view;
            }
        }
```